# From two rows, return the row containing numbers/string character

Tags: mysql, sql

I am running a mysql query iterating over a large data set. After running the query I am returned with the below rows.

```
id | location
123| USA
45A| Canada
```

What I'd like to do is return the second row, whose id contains numbers and letters. It's not always the case that I'll have 2 rows so I cannot return the last value or try `ORDER by...desc`.

What I've tried is using regex inserting the below statement before returning

```
WHERE someId REGEXP '^([0-9]+[a-zA-Z]+|[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+)[0-9a-zA-Z]*$'
```

But, this errors out and doesn't return anything. My expected output should return the 2nd row.

Comment: what is the pattern you are trying to match?

Comment: What does "errors out" mean, specifically?

Comment: @nicomp I am running the query in sequel pro and this is the error message: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE someID REGEXP '[^0-9]'
         ORDER BY someID DESC' at line 13

Comment: Usually, MySQL error messages start where the problem did; in this case, it seems like it didn't even like your use of the `WHERE clause`; what preceded it in the query? Post the full, query or a reasonable facsimile of the full query.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return the rows that have a non-digit, then you can do:

```
where someId regexp '[^0-9]'
```

Answer (score 0):

To match on row(s) that contains both numbers and letters :

```
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE( someId, '[[:alpha:]]') AND REGEXP_LIKE( someId, '[[:digit:]]')
```